# AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'nx_pydot'

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, virtualenv, networkx, attributeerror

I'm trying to execute a python file named demo.py (which imports another file takahe2.py) in python virtual environment with python3.7. I am trying to get the output of some strings as text in a .txt file. But when I run the code it shows the output in the console but failed to create a .txt file, showing this error:

`File "/home/user/takahe2.py", line 932, in write_dot`

`nx.nx_pydot.write_dot(self.graph, dotfile)`

`AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'nx_pydot'`

In takahe2.py:

I have imported these:

`from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot`
`from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot`

Corresponding function in takahe2.py:

```
 `def write_dot(self, dotfile):`
    """ Outputs the word graph in dot format in the specified file. """
    
    # nx.write_dot(self.graph, dotfile)
    nx.nx_pydot.write_dot(self.graph, dotfile)`
```

The actual file I'm trying to run demo.py: (Portion of the code is shown where error occurred:)

`for i in range(1,140):`

```
serial_no = str(i)
document = open('DataSet/Source/'+serial_no+'.txt').read()
doc = sentTokenizer.sentTokenizing().sentTokenize(document)
print('doc',doc)

filenamee, n = clustering.startF(doc)
print("\n\nSource:",document)

summary = getSummary(filenamee)
print('\n\nSummary:',summary)

# save the summary
createFolder('DataSet/')
fi = open('DataSet/'+serial_no+'.txt','+w')
fi.write(summary)
```

My networkx version is 1.7. Os: Linux

Comment: Thanks to all the people who didn't answer. I figured out the answer myself. I needed to install these in my python virtual environment:

`pip install pydot`

 `pip install pydotplus`

Comment: Update: Also, I needed to update the  write_dot(self, dotfile) function according to @Hassan's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73422123/18734745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `nx.drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot(self.graph, dotfile)` instead of `nx.nx_pydot.write_dot(self.graph, dotfile)` in the takahe2.py file.
2. Install this package:

   `pip install pydot`
3. Don't forget to import these in your file:

   `import networkx as nx`

   `from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot`

   `from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot`

   `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

For safety, I would install the following packages as well.

```
 pip install pydotplus
 pip install pyqt5
 sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0 
 sudo apt-get install graphviz graphviz-dev
 pip install pygraphviz
```